# Reference-able custom section numbering

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, amsthm

I am writing some lecture notes from a class that I have on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday.  What I would like to do is organize them by sections defined by the week and the day, e.g. 1M, 1W, 1F, 2M, 2W, 2F, 3M, and so on.  Furthermore, when I reference a labeled theorem in that section, I would like it to show up as something like "Theorem 2F.1" or "Proposition 3M.7".

(I'm imagining something like

> `\section[1M]{January 6th, 2014: Applications of Nakayama's Lemma}`
>
> `\begin{theorem}\label{Nakayama} ... \end{theorem}`
>
> (...then, later...)
>
> `...Thus, it follows by \ref{Nakayama} that...`

which would output "...Thus, it follows by Theorem 1M.1 that...")

Is there any way to create a custom numbering scheme that is able to be referenced like this?  What's the closest I can get to it?

Comment: Are you *only* referencing `theorem`s, or other parts of your document as well? Are you using a Table of Contents at all?

Comment: @Werner Ideally, I would like to be able to reference several different types (specifically `theorem`s, `proposition`s, `corollary`s, `example`s, and `note`s, on the same numbering system).  I know how to do this with standard environments.  A ToC might be a nice idea at the end but it doesn't matter too much to me.

Comment: Are you using any special packages to create your theorems?

Comment: @Werner I believe they come from `amsthm`. (Which I like; but I'm not married to it.)

Comment: So `1M` should form part of the section title? Or should that be the actual section "number"? It's not clear from your post, but [you mentioned it in comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6537/alexander-nikolas-gruber).

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\renewcommand\thesection{\the\numexpr(1+\value{section})/3\relax
                          \ifcase\the\numexpr 2+ \value{section}-(3*((1+\the\value{section})/3))\relax
                           M\or W\or F%
                           \fi}
\begin{document}

\section{zzz}\label{z}  xxx

\section{aaa} see \ref{z} and \ref{d} and \ref{l} and \ref{ll}

\section{bbb} vvv
\begin{lemma}\label{l}llllll\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}\label{ll}llllll\end{lemma}

\section{cc} vvv
\section{ddd}\label{d} vvv
\section{eee} vvv
\section{ff} vvv
\section{ggg} vvv
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this.  `\section{January...}` correctly produces "1M January..." for the section heading, but `\begin{theorem}\label{Nakayama} ... \end{theorem}` followed by `...\ref{Nakayama}...` just outputs Theorem 1, rather than Theorem 1M.1.

Comment: @AlexanderNikolasGruber the `\newtheorem` command has an optional argument to say theorems should be numbered within section

Comment: @AlexanderNikolasGruber added a `\newtheorem` example

Answer (score 2):

Each counter, when `\refstep`ped, stores its contents in `\@currentlabel` which is used as the reference. However, they are also prepended with some "parent reference". You can update this parent reference for theorem (called `\p@theorem`) as being the optional argument of `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsthm,etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\p@section}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\@xsect}% <search>
  {\xdef\p@theorem{#7.}\@xsect}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><replace>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section[1M]{January 6th, 2014: Applications of Nakayama's Lemma}

blah

\begin{theorem}\label{Nakayama}
blah blah
\end{theorem}

Some more blah. Thus, it follows by Theorem~\ref{Nakayama} that

\end{document}
```

One may have to do some more work to remove any content if you don't supply an optional argument to `\section`.

If you want this for other theorem-like environments (like `proposition`s, `lemma`s, ...), then you can just add these as part of the replacement text `<replace>` in the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch.